# After being heated and cooled why does Coconut Oil form these structures?

Tags: solid-state-physics, structure-formation

According the the guy who posted this picture, the coconut oil melted during a heatwave and then re-solidified into hexagonal structures.

[image]

I looked into foam physics and it seems that area deals with a lot of these similar patterns. Could someone tell me why this happens? Is it something specific to the structure of the oil? But if it is, why is this pattern replicated across many systems in natures. Like the giant's causeway in Ireland.

[image]

This is said have formed as Lava cooled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer probably lies in what are called [Rayleigh–Bénard convection cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93B%C3%A9nard_convection) that often form hexagonal structures.

> Buoyancy, and hence gravity, is responsible for the appearance of
>   convection cells. The initial movement is the upwelling of lesser
>   density fluid from the heated bottom layer.[3] This upwelling
>   spontaneously organizes into a regular pattern of cells.